# Continued run in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a code in Python. Within the code, a blackbox application written in c++ is called. Sometimes this c++ application does not converge and an error message come up. This error does not terminate the Python code, but it pause the run. After clicking ok for the error message, the python code continues running till either the end of the code or the message comes up again. Is there a way to handle this problem within Python: the code detects the message and clicks ok?

Thanks

Comment: totally depends on how you call your c++ blackbox.

Comment: Does it throw an exception? What brings up the error box, the C++ program or the python program? Do you need it to physically move the mouse? I think there isn't enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: when you say "this error does not terminate the Python code", do you mean the c++ code?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reposne. The application is called using "subprocess.check_call" command.

Comment: @Jack: The C++ code id called in the Python code. The C++ code sometimes gives an error. In such case, I physically move the mouse to click ok. Once I do it, the Python code continues running

Comment: @bj0: There is a loop in the Python code. Within this loop, the C++ code is called. If the C++ code gives error, then I have to click ok and then Python continues running and going to the next step in the loop.

Comment: Seems more of a C++ blackbox issue than a python one...

Comment: @Bruce: You're right. There is no problem with Python and the error is from the C++ code. But I don't have access to the source code of C++ application. So I am wondering if there is a way to add some codes to Python, so Python detects the error message and clicks OK.

Comment: you can start a thread and kill the process after a while : it's the harsh way but it works if your external blackbox takes roughly the same amount of time (or at least is bound by an upper limit)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in your case Python program doesn't actually continue the execution, unless the program started as a subprocess completes - this is the behaviour or [subprocess.check_call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) which you say is used to start the subprocess.

As long as you start a subprocess with `check_call`, there is pretty much no way to find out the intermediate subprocess state, until it actually terminates and you get the exit code.

So, instead you may use [subprocess.Popen()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) constructor to create a [Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) object, which starts the subprocess, but doesn't wait for subprocess to complete. This way you can verify the subprocess state implicitly by checking its other outputs, if any hopefully exist for it (for example you may as well read subprocess output if you know it writes its errors or other messages to stdout or stderr).

P.S. Better solution - fix the C++ program.

Answer (score 0):

Timur is correct.  Unless the C++ program explicitly provides a way for you to check the status, respond to the dialog, or make it run without showing the dialog, there is nothing built into python that can solve this problem as far as i know.

There are some workarounds that might work for you, though.  Depending on your platform, you could use a window manager extension module (like pywin32 or python-xlib) to search for the dialog box and programatically click the Ok.

If you can use Jython, you can use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/), which is a very nice, easy to use visual automation package.